# JxBrowser speculative execution side channel Spectre vulnerability

Tags: jxbrowser

Is JxBrowser impacted by the recent speculative execution Spectre vulnerabilities as JxBrowser is based on Chromium? If so, what steps can users take to resolve the vulnerability?

Chromium guidance can be found at

https://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/ssca

https://support.google.com/faqs/answer/7622138

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a support request.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Unfortunately, Site Isolation feature that is mentioned in the Google answer is not supported by JxBrowser and cannot be used to mitigate exploitation of these vulnerabilities in the current version, which is based on Chromium 60.

Right now, we are working on upgrading to Chromium 64. This update will be available in one of the following versions of JxBrowser.